# Standard method of viewController not called Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

This standard method is not called

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated:Bool) {
    saveData() 
    print("Data are saved")
}
```

What method could I call for saving data before

> force closing

viewController?

Comment: forget `super.viewWillDisappear(animated)` ?

Comment: why not call it during the function that closes the view controller?

Comment: @Sh_Khan       it didn't help

Comment: @Jay           user sometimes force close

Comment: the above method is called when the vc is about to be dismissed / popped , for app notifications consider enterBackground / foreground then save your data inside them

Comment: viewWillDissapear is only called, when the associated view, is removed from the view hierarchy.

Comment: Don't wait until the last moment to save your data.

Answer (score 0):

> What method could I call for saving data before force closing viewController?

You should save data in the app delegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (choose one of these):

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    if parent == nil {
        // place for your code
        saveData() 
        print("Data are saved")
    }
}

override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    if parent == nil {
        // place for your code
        saveData() 
        print("Data are saved")
    }
}
```